# Ansible replace command is not working find module

Tags: ansible

I am new to Ansible, I have to find some file and then replace some pattern in the all files. so I am using the find and replace module as follows.

```
- name: My Great Playbook
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: False
  accelerate: False
  strategy: free
  vars:
    dbname: "@DBNAME@"
    repldbname: "connect to mydb"

  tasks:
   - block:
      - name: finding fl
        find:
          paths: "/home/username1/temp"
          patterns: "*.sql"
          file_type: "file"
        register: repos

      - name: some thing
        debug: msg="{{ item }}"
        with_items: "{{ repos.files }}"

      - name: replacing string
        replace:
           path: "{{ item }}"
           #path: "/home/username1/temp/1.sql"
           regexp: ({{ dbname }})
           replace: '{{ repldbname }}'
           backup: no
           unsafe_writes: yes
        with_items: "{{ repos.files }}"
```

I am getting following error as follows

```
failed: [localhost] (item={u'uid': 575479814, u'woth': True, u'mtime': 1504541305.603901, u'inode': 8433422, u'isgid': False, u'size': 256, u'roth': True, u'isuid': False, u'isreg': True, u'gid': 575144449, u'ischr': False, u'wusr': True, u'xoth': True, u'rusr': True, u'nlink': 1, u'issock': False, u'rgrp': True, u'path': u'/home/username1/temp/1.sql', u'xusr': True, u'atime': 1504541305.604901, u'isdir': False, u'ctime': 1504541305.6059012, u'wgrp': True, u'xgrp': True, u'dev': 64772, u'isblk': False, u'isfifo': False, u'mode': u'0777', u'islnk': False}) => {
    "failed": true,
    "item": {
        "atime": 1504541305.604901,
        "ctime": 1504541305.6059012,
        "dev": 64772,
        "gid": 575144449,
        "inode": 8433422,
        "isblk": false,
        "ischr": false,
        "isdir": false,
        "isfifo": false,
        "isgid": false,
        "islnk": false,
        "isreg": true,
        "issock": false,
        "isuid": false,
        "mode": "0777",
        "mtime": 1504541305.603901,
        "nlink": 1,
        "path": "/home/username1/temp/1.sql",
        "rgrp": true,
        "roth": true,
        "rusr": true,
        "size": 256,
        "uid": 575479814,
        "wgrp": true,
        "woth": true,
        "wusr": true,
        "xgrp": true,
        "xoth": true,
        "xusr": true
    },
    "rc": 257
}
```

MSG:

> Path {'uid': 575479814, 'woth': True, 'mtime': 1504541305.603901, 'inode': 8433422, 'isgid': False, 'size': 256, 'wgrp': True, 'isuid': False, 'isreg': True, 'gid': 575144449, 'ischr': False, 'wusr': True, 'xoth': True, 'islnk': False, 'nlink': 1, 'issock': False, 'rgrp': True, 'path': '/home/username1/temp/1.sql', 'xusr': True, 'atime': 1504541305.604901, 'isdir': False, 'ctime': 1504541305.6059012, 'isblk': False, 'xgrp': True, 'dev': 64772, 'roth': True, 'isfifo': False, 'mode': '0777', 'rusr': True} does not exist !

Please let me know what is issue here ?

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
path: "{{ item }}"
```

With:

```
path: "{{ item.path }}"
```

You are trying to pass a dictionary object to an argument which requires a string value.